# Geospatial queries over Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, geospatial, objectify

The documentation for Google Cloud Datastore details the *Geographical point* data type [1]. While there is no *strictly* corresponding class in the Java library, there is a `LatLng` class [2] that seems to be the canonical equivalent.

While I can store the value just fine, and I can query for *exact* locations by supplying a fully constructed `LatLng` instance like this:

```
ofy.load().type(Site.class) // Site is a custom class, whose latLng field is a LatLng-type
        .filter("latLng", LatLng.of(26.329,127.744))
        .first()
        .now()
```

I can't seem to do *inexact* queries natively, at least not on the Console. Though I can *kind of* do something like it in Objectify:

```
ofy.load().type(Site.class)
        .filter("latLng >", LatLng.of(26.0,127.0))
        .filter("latLng <", LatLng.of(90,127.750))
        .first()
        .now()
```

My question is: is there native/first-class support for geospatial queries in the Datastore? Or is this sort of coordinate geometry-"hackery" the only accepted way of doing such searches/queries?

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#geographical_point
[2] https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/0.111.0-alpha/com/google/cloud/datastore/LatLng.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like Datastore *does*, in fact, handle the `LatLng` type natively, allowing you to do inexact queries over it. All the various restrictions of inexact queries apply (there can be only one inexactly-queried attribute, it must be indexed, etc.), and the index size for the type (16 bytes) suggests an internal representation of a pair of `double`s, and experimentation seems to suggest the query operates by filtering *latitudes* first, then *longitudes*.

However, it is currently handled incorrectly, and a bounding box-query, as the one in the opening question, also returns points that satisfy only one of the constraints (in my case, the *latitude* of some points satisfied the constraint but not the *longitude*).

I've reported the issue to Google via the issue tracker, and they have reproduced it internally, forwarding it to the Datastore team for resolution. I will update this answer once I hear back from them.

Comment: Could you share the issue link? Is it fixed?

Comment: @Tom, here's the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143165181
They ended up deciding it's working as intended, though...

Answer (score 0):

According to the following document GQL has two flavors. The flavor used in Python NDB/DB has GEOPT function to do spatial queries. But the flavor that is used in the console doesn't have this and a few other functions.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference

Exact statement from the above reference

"Python GQL supports functions DATETIME, DATE, TIME, KEY, USER, and GEOPT. Cloud Datastore GQL supports function DATETIME and KEY, but with different arguments. Cloud Datastore GQL supports function BLOB. Cloud Datastore GQL does not support GEOPT."